# как занести значение 8 по адресу z? int z

Tags: c++, visual-c++, переменные, int

```
    int* z;
    *z = 8; 
    cout << "\n прочитаем значение переменной через ее адрес" << *z;
    return 0;
```

во второй строчке пишет: Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи.
z было nullptr.
что с этим делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: можете вставить код, приведенный выше, в вижуал студио? после запуска во второй строке выдаст ошибку. как ее справить?

Comment: Не предоставлена чёткая задача. Программа написана правильно, по адресу *неопределённое значение* вы хотите поменять значение. Что вам не нравится?

Comment: при проверке появляются две ошибки: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная z и вторая : build errors occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1

```
int* z = new int;
*z = 8;
```

Вариант 2

```
int q;
int* z = &q;
*z = 8;
```

Что именно вы хотите? *Как именно* исправить?

Comment: спасибо большое!! все получилось